# why we use instance as second parameter instead first in Django forms for existing db entry

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I see instance need to pass as second argument in the model forms to edit the existing entry of DB.. but why we are not passing it as first arg

```
>>> from myapp.models import Article
>>> from myapp.forms import ArticleForm

# Create a form instance from POST data.
>>> f = ArticleForm(request.POST)

# Save a new Article object from the form's data.
>>> new_article = f.save()

# Create a form to edit an existing Article, but use
# POST data to populate the form.
>>> a = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> **f = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a)**
>>> f.save()
```

can you help me to understand this... !!

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ModelForm inherits from ModelBaseForm, which again inherits from BaseForm, which lead to a lot of possible arguments.

```
class BaseForm:
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                 empty_permitted=False, field_order=None, use_required_attribute=None, renderer=None):

class BaseModelForm(BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                 empty_permitted=False, instance=None, use_required_attribute=None,
                 renderer=None):

class ModelForm(BaseModelForm, metaclass=ModelFormMetaclass):
    pass
```

So in your example, instance is the second argument, but its a keyword argument. This allows to skip several other argument, as those will receive its default value. Actually instance would be 9th argument.

If you prefer to have instance as a first argument in your initialisation of the form, this is actually possible because of the keyword arguments.

Do it like this:

```
f = ArticleForm(instance=a, data=request.POST)
```